# Select ListBox Item based on Textbox text

Tags: c#, wpf

here's what i'm trying to do :
i've got a textbox and a listbox :

```
 <GroupBox Header="SAISIE ADRESSE">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Content="ADRESSE"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AdrManuel_Textbox" Height="30"
                             Text="{Binding SearchText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="SearchPicking_LB" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                             MouseDoubleClick="SearchPicking_LB_MouseDoubleClick"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding MyFilteredItems}" Background="LightGray"
                             Width="150" Height="100" Margin="8"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Then the user for example can write "30" into the textbox and all the items in the listbox that contains "30" will be displayed.

[image: Pics]

but the cs code is not working (as you can see on the picture), but no errors are throwned.

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Adr_Palettes : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return _searchText; }
        set
        {
            _searchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchText");
        }
    }

    public List<string> MyItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> MyFilteredItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (SearchText == null) return MyItems;
            return MyItems.Where(x=>x.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper()));
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }

    public Adr_Palettes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void SearchPicking_LB_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using(BdCretsDataContext dc=new BdCretsDataContext())
        {
            var picking = (from p in dc.PICKING
                          where p.ART_CODE == null && p.ENT_ID == null
                          orderby p.R_ID
                          select new
                          {
                              p.R_ADRESSE
                          }).ToList();
            SearchPicking_LB.ItemsSource = picking.Select(row => row.R_ADRESSE);
            MyItems = new List<string>();

            foreach (string item in SearchPicking_LB.Items)
            {
                MyItems.Add(item);
            }
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below.
Change your MyFilteredList as below

public IList MyFilteredList

{

```
 get;
 private set;
```

}= new ObserverableCollection();

Add below private method

private void Filter()
   {

```
    MyFilteredList.Clear();
   foreach(string s in MyItems)
   {
     if(SearchText==null||s.Toupper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
       { 
              MyFilteredList.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

In the set of your SearchText property call Filtert method this should work for you.

This is actually expanded version of your solution with difference of updating same object of MyFilitetedList

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution.

For code:

```
public string SearchText 
{
    get { return _searchText; } 
    set
    {
        if (_searchText == value)
            return;
        _searchText = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("SearchText");
        OnPropertyChanged("MyFilteredItems"); 
    } 
}
```

And a suggestion for the UI code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="AdrManuel_Textbox" Height="30"
                         Text="{Binding SearchText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=250}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But it didn't change anything